# Wordpress replace all ocurrances of the string in admin

Tags: wordpress, code-translation

I am trying to change the words for various places in Wordpress Admin, for example, change the name of "Dashboard" to something else, but I want it to change across the entire Admin - all the occurances. I tried searching through admin files and replacing words, but this is just too much time consuming. 
I don't need the words to be translatable, is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this code to the function.php file of your child theme:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'dirty_translate'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'dirty_translate'  );
function dirty_translate( $translated ) {
     $words = array(
            // 'word to translate' => 'translation'
            'Dashboard' => 'Foo',
            'Add new' => 'Bar'
     );
$translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
return $translated;
}
```

Just replace the translations with your own. You can add as many translations as you need. I'm using this myself - Tested and works.