# Replace multiple strings or texts

Tags: php, wordpress, string, function, replace

This code within *functions.php* works very fine if you have to replace or translate one string or text in WordPress, in any page:

```
//The filters.. both are required.
add_filter('gettext', 'change_cancellation_btn');
add_filter('ngettext', 'change_cancellation_btn');

//function
function change_cancellation_btn($cancellation_btn){
$cancellation_btn = str_ireplace('text to replace', 'new text', $cancellation_btn);
return $cancellation_btn;
}
```

How can I use the same code to replace multiple strings or texts?

In my case I replaced the texts in two different buttons and to do it I used the same code twice:

```
//The filters.. both are required.
add_filter('gettext', 'change_cancellation_btn');
add_filter('ngettext', 'change_cancellation_btn');

//function button 1
function change_cancellation_btn($cancellation_btn){
$cancellation_btn = str_ireplace('text 1 to replace', 'new text 1', $cancellation_btn);
return $cancellation_btn;
}


//The filters.. both are required.
add_filter('gettext', 'change_nocancellation_btn');
add_filter('ngettext', 'change_nocancellation_btn');

//function button 2
function change_nocancellation_btn($nocancellation_btn){
$nocancellation_btn = str_ireplace('text 2 to replace', 'new text 2', $nocancellation_btn);
return $nocancellation_btn;
}
```

So, is there a way to replace multiple strings with one function?

Comment: [str_ireplace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) can accept arrays, see the manual.

Comment: thank you, I see it, but I'm not very experienced with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use switch case like below:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_comment_field_names', 20, 3 );
function theme_change_comment_field_names( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
 
        case 'text 1 to replace' :
 
            $translated_text = __( 'new text 1', 'theme_text_domain' );
            break;
 
        case 'text 2 to replace' :
 
            $translated_text = __( 'new text 2', 'theme_text_domain' );
            break;
    }    
 
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
Call the function inside the loop
and pass the parameter by creating an array or if you from a database similar its work.

e.g:
$array = array(
array(
'text_to_replace' => 'Dummy',
'new_text' => 'Test',
'text_content'=> 'Dummy content string'
))

//function
function change_cancellation_btn($text_to_replace, $new_text, $text_content){
$changedText = str_ireplace($text_to_replace, $new_text, $text_content);
return $changedText;
}


Now call the change_cancellation_btn by running the loop of the array by passing multiple contents.
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE. This works better for me, because it replaces/translates all strings in admin backend, too:

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'dirty_translate'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'dirty_translate'  );
function dirty_translate( $translated ) {
     $words = array(
            // 'word to translate' => 'translation'
            'Dashboard' => 'Foo',
            'Add new' => 'Bar'
     );
$translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
return $translated;
}
```

Ref: [Wordpress replace all ocurrances of the string in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247729/wordpress-replace-all-ocurrances-of-the-string-in-admin/50247776#50247776)